# Explain the proper syntax for setting fields using the material-expansion panel from dart angular 2 material

Tags: html, angular, dart

I am using this repository: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components

The following code chunk is from app_component.html. I added the asignment: disableHeaderExpansion to the material-expansion panel. Everything works fine because I surrounded disableHeaderExpansion with brackets.

```
  <material-expansionpanel name="Expansion panel" [disableHeaderExpansion]="true">
    <div>
      Oh hi. I was just trying not to take too much space here.
    </div>
  </material-expansionpanel>
```

When I remove the brackets surrounding disableHeaderExpansion, the components do not appear properly. I looked at the MaterialExpansionPanel in the Angular 2 components:

```
 /// If true, clicking on the header does not expand or collapse the panel.
  @Input()
  bool disableHeaderExpansion = false;

  /// A short name label for the expansion panel.
  @Input()
  String name;
```

When I place brackets on the name field, the components do not appear as well.

Why do I need to put brackets on the disableHeaderExpansion, but I should not put brackets on the name field? I would expect that I need to put brackets on the name field.

After typing this question out I realized this could be the answer.

Is this an exception because Html already has a name attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#remember-the-brackets), We should omit the brackets when all of the following are true:

- The target property accepts a string value.
- The string is a fixed value that we can bake into the template.
- This initial value never
  changes.

because of it you can omit the brackets for your `name` field.

The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If we forget the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string. So because of this when you remove brackets from `disableHeaderExpansion` field Angular treats it as string but you have declare it as `bool` with `@Input` which makes component property initialization wrong and because of it your components do not appear properly.